# What are pending signals?

Tags: linux, process, signals, ulimit

When looking at the limits of a running process, I see

```
Max pending signals       15725
```

- What is this?
- How can I determine a sensible value for a busy service?

Generally, I can't seem to find a page that explains what each limit is. Some are pretty self-explanatory (max open files), some less so (max msgqueue size).

Comment: On a nearly up-to-date Arch linux, kernel 3.14.37-1-lts, zsh, I get `sigpending      31603`. Why are these limits such weird numbers (i.e. not a power of 2)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigpending) of `sigpending`:

> sigpending() returns the set of signals that are pending for delivery
>   to the calling thread (i.e., the signals which have been raised while
>   blocked).

So, it is meant the signals (sigterm, sigkill, sigstop, ...) that are waiting until the process comes out of the `D` (uninterruptible sleep) state. Usually a process is in that state when it is waiting for I/O. That sleep can't be interrupted. Even sigkill (`kill -9`) can't and the kernel waits until the process wakes up (the signal is pending for delivery so long).

For the other unclear values, I would take a look in the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) of `limits.conf`.

Comment: It's the manual pages for `sigqueue` and `setrlimit` that you really should be looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Process limits are controled by setrlimit(2)

So you can look into its manpage:

> RLIMIT_SIGPENDING (Since Linux 2.6.8)
>
> Specifies the limit on the number of signals that may be  queued for  the real user ID of the calling process.  Both standard and real-time signals are counted for the purpose of  checking  this limit.   However, the limit is enforced only for sigqueue(3); it is always possible to use kill(2) to queue one instance  of  any of the signals that are not already queued to the process.

Generally, you can get the most detailed information when you look into manpages of syscalls. C is the mother tongue of UNIX/Linux.